# Is it possible to show access-restricted pages in typo3 solr search result to non-logged-in users?

Tags: search, solr, typo3

The [default behaviour](http://www.typo3-solr.com/en/solr-for-typo3/development-model/indexing/frontend-user-group-access-restrictions/) of t3solr is to hide results with access restrictions if the currently logged in user does not have the rights to see this page (or is not logged in at all).

Our customer wants a different behaviour: the results shall be displayed, but be visually highlighted (by adding a css class, for instance). The (not yet logged in) user can "preview" an abstract of the desired content in the search result excerpt (to tease him) and click the link. He will then be presented the login page and redirected to his target page after login (last part is already default typo3 behaviour).

Does anyone know whether this is possible with the current t3solr? I think it was possible with indexed_search when I last used it some years ago, so I thought t3solr may support this as well.

And no, I have not "just" tried it out yet as setting up the whole stuff takes longer than asking here before. Also, I'm not sure whether I have to pay for the early access version of the t3solr to get this (possible) feature.

Comment: Did you manage to integrate the feature back then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions of the TYPO3 extension Apache Solr are identical regarding the access rights to pages and content elements.

The requirements you are stating are not going to work out of the box as we designed the extension to be very strict on displaying only results that you are allowed to see.

There is certainly a way to circumvent the behaviour that would require a change in the solr access filter that we have in the extension. Or by assigning access rights on content level and and having a plugin displaying a teasing part only.

We generally monitor questions about solr for TYPO3 here:

news://lists.typo3.org:119/typo3.projects.solr

Comment: Fast forward. It is now 2019. Did this feature made it into solr for typo3 yet?